# OpenCVでのwindow_QT.cpp, line 1193エラー

Tags: opencv

http://opencv.jp/sample/simple_gui.html
の一番上の「トラックバーの利用 cvCreateTrackbar, cvGetTrackbarPos, cvSetTrackbarPos」のサンプルプログラムを動かしたところ

```
init done 
opengl support available 
OpenCV Error: Null pointer (NULL value pointer) in addSlider, file /home/aaa/Desktop/opencv-3.0.0/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp, line 1193
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/aaa/Desktop/opencv-3.0.0/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp:1193: error: (-27) NULL value pointer in function addSlider

Aborted (core dumped)
Enterキーを押すと、ターミナルが終了します...
```

とエラーが表示されました。NULLが何かに設定されているのが原因かと思いブレークポイントを設定しようとしましたがブレークポイントが設定できず`cvWaitKey(0);`を`main`に入ってすぐのところに設定しましたが`main`にすら入っていないようで何が原因か特定できません。

心当たりがあるとすれば、インストールに戸惑い結果的に複数のバージョンをインストールした可能性があることです。